# How to insert symbols in a post?

Tags: support, markdown

[Reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3765641)

If you see the above post, you'll see these character that were used to describe the directory structure -

```
├──, └──
```

And I see several other on similar lines in other posts. I would like to know how to enter these symbols. I have copy-pasted these from that post, but that's not the way to do it.

Please let me know.

Comment: If you see content written in a question / answer that you want to find out how it was done you can 'edit' that question to look directly at the markdown used.

Comment: Unicode box drawing characters.

Comment: Well, you can find the character in your character map or online, or you can try and figure out the Alt-Code that produces it. Whatever is more convenient for you. However, this really has nothing to do with Stack Exchange. They're Unicode characters, it's not something the site produces through any special circumstances.

Comment: @JonW That's how I copied it from there... But there's nothing specific tag or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Unicode characters from the [Box Drawing block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).

In the post, I assume the directory tree was copied and pasted from one of the command-line programs that pretty-print trees, which will automatically pick the right box-drawing characters.

On Linux, you can generate such a tree using the `tree -F` command (`-F` tells it to use Unicode).

Windows has a `tree` command that does the same thing.

Comment: So we have to copy-paste it, we don't have any key combinations to insert them into the post. I tried tricks with `Alt` + `x` key, but nothing happens. It would be great, if there is some way we can insert them into the text area without any external program help, as it might not be available always.

Comment: @mtk: These characters aren't very commonly used. It makes little sense for Stack Exchange to reimplement functionality for inserting obscure characters; you should use software (i.e. the character map) designed for that purpose.

Comment: cool. Thanks for the info.